# Why do .py files always save before running in Spyder despite disabling the option?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have already disabled the selected choice by clicking on Tools > Preferences > Editor > Advanced Tab and then unchecking the “save files after each run” radio button, but whenever I run a file it still shows up.

There’s no other relevant question addressing this issue on here or any major Anaconda-related forum, so I would appreciate advice to solve the bug.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run a `*.py` file without saving it first. So, while you try to run the file, it implicitly saves the file first and then runs. That is true regardless of your editor / IDE of choice.

Comment: There is listed very explicitly an option to disable that feature. After all, otherwise how could I test out portions of my code without losing the rest of them?